# How to add google drive sdk Example dynamically via jQuery in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

It's simple but I can't do it. I can do it in normal way in a index.html, but I need to add and run that code dynamically.
I'm trying to copy paste the example from Drive SDK Page https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // APPEND THE INPUT FROM THE EXAMPLE CODE
  jQuery('body').append('<input type="file" id="filePicker" style="visibility: hidden" />');

  / ** CONTINUE THE SDK EXAMPLE CODE **/
  var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
  function handleClientLoad() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
  }
  [...]
  / ** FINISH THE EXAMPLE CODE **/

  // APPEND THE SCRIPT FROM EXAMPLE CODE
  jQuery('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>');
});
```

Will it ever work that way ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is the picker library ever getting loaded?

Comment: The input is appended to body but the script tag is not to the head

Comment: Used jQuery.getScript() and it worked.